# how read pdf using itext and java and get table cell height

Tags: java, pdf, itext

First I have created a pdf using itext and java and put a table and tableCell

```
 PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
        table.setWidths(new int[]{1, 2});
        PdfPCell cell;
        table.addCell("Address:");
        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(""));
        cell.setFixedHeight(60);
        table.addCell(cell);
```

I have another Program Which read this pdf File

```
  PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("path_of_previously_created_pdf");
```

Now i want to get TableCell cell and want to Change cell height  cell.setFixedHeight(new_Fixed_Height);

It is possible... if Yes .
How??
Thanx in advance

Answer (score 1):

If your PDF contains just that simple 1x2 table, it of course would be possible to implement something that gives you the PDF with a cell hight of you choice.

But I assume it eventually is meant to contain more. Already the code you provided via your google drive included more (more table cells plus form elements), and that code, too, does look unfinished concerning the PDF construction. *Thus,...*

## The direct answer

It is not possible.

First of all the `table` and `cell` objects you have while creating the PDF are not present as such in the resulting file, they merely are drawn as a number of lines and some text (or whatever you put into the cells).

Thus, you cannot even retrieve the `cells` you want to change, let alone change it.

## The twisted answer

You could, of course, try and parse the page content stream to find the commands for drawing lines, find those ones among them which were drawn for the `cell` you are interested in, and try to derive the original `cell` dimension attributes from the line coordinates. Afterwards you can attempt to move everything below the cell down to create the extra space you want.

Depending on the information you have (Do you know the approximate position of the cell? If not, do you at least know some unique content of it?) reading the current cell height will include some guesswork and much coding because unfortunately the iText parser framework does not yet support parsing path operations.

Essentially you have to enhance the classes in the PDF parser package to also process and emit events for PDF path operators (if you know your way around in iText and the PDF specification that should not take more than a week or two) and create an appropriate event listener to find the lines surrounding the cell position you already know (not more than one day of work). Some iText code analysis will show how the fixed cell height and the distance of the surrounding lines relate.

Most likely, though, this is the smaller part of your work. The bigger part is actually manipulating the page content:

If you are lucky, all your page content is located in a single content stream. In that case you merely have to analyse all the page content again but this time to actually change it. The easiest way would be to enhance the classes in the parser package once again (because they already do much of the necessary math and book-keeping) to signal every command from the content stream with normalized coordinates (this might take a week or two). Based on this information signaled to you built an all new content stream in which you leave everything above your cell, move down everything below, and stretch everything crossing the line on which the bottom border of your cell lies (another week maybe).

If you are less lucky you have to fight with multiple included form xobjects crossing the line. As those xobjects may be used from other streams also, you cannot change them but have to either change a copy or include the xobject content in your newly created stream.

Then what about images crossing the line? or interesting patterns? In that case stretching the cell will utterly distort everything.

And then there are annotations, e.g. your form fields. You need to shift and stretch them, too.

Thus, while this approach is possible to follow, please be aware that (depending on how generic the solution has to become) its implementation will take someone knowing iText and PDF some months.

## An alternative approach

You say in a comment

> I am working on Pdf Form.I have created itext form using TextField(MULTILINE TEXT) once. After read this pdf and fill up the form but when the content increases it shows scroll Bar and content hide. My problem is Once i print the pdf it did't print hide content.

Why don't you simply for each set of data build an individual PDF with all the cells big enough for the form contents of the respective data set and copy the field values into this new PDF. This is a fairly simple approach, yet flexible enough to not waste too much space but at the same time not hide content.

Comment: (Do you know the approximate position of the cell? Yes i know the position. then how get/set cell height??

Comment: You enhance the classes in the PDF parser package to also process and emit events for PDF path operators (if you know your way around in iText and the PDF specification that should not take more than a week or two) and create an appropriate event listener to find the lines surrounding the cell position you already know (not more than one day of work). Some iText code analysis will show how the fixed cell height and the distance of the surrounding lines relate.

Comment: @mkl...Thanx for your interest.....  I am working on Pdf Form.I have created itext form using  TextField(MULTILINE TEXT) once.  After read this pdf and fill up the form but when the content increases it shows scroll Bar and content hide.  My problem is **Once i print the pdf it did't print hide content.**  i have followed [This Link](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=157)  and create form and filled form

Comment: *Once i print the pdf it did't print hide content* - Well, yes, that's what it means to be hidden. So essentially you have to re-create the original form with a larger text field. If you need help with that, add additional information to you original question, especially include the code to create the text field and explain what keeps you from simply increasing the cell size.

Comment: my code is  my code  https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0Bx-vPdiakjsbQm1PdDZKcV9panc&usp=sharing

Comment: ... and explain what keeps you from simply increasing the cell size

Comment: @mkl.... I supposed u have seen my code.  If item number is increases then how i set(increase/decrease) Tablecell size accordingly in FillingFormClass. If you any idea please let me know.

Comment: Oh, I only now see that you actually want to change a cell height (I initially have not realized that, maybe because calculating it already is hard enough). Thus, to clarify, do you actually want to resize the table cell, shifting down content located below? Or do you, in your actual use case, have some free space and only Need to resize the Form field?

Comment: do you actually want to resize the table cell, shifting down content located below?  My answer is **YES**

Comment: I'm sorry I initially mis-interpreted your question. I updated my answer. In a few words: Don't try to change the finished PDF afterwards; instead generate a new one for each data set with big enough cells for the respective data. Everything else likely is Herculean.